# Rails: multiple-class methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm presenting users a list of assets they've created. They can be different classes, and each has an edit button.

What'd be the best way to write a method that takes the user to the correct edit form depending on what the class is?

Something like this is what I'm thinking:

```
def edit_asset(class, id)
  if class == 'Photo'
    redirect_to edit_photo_url(id)
  elsif class == 'Audio'
    redirect_to edit_audio_url(id)
  elsif ...
    ...
  end
end
```

Is there a better way to do this? Any where should this method go? Thanks!

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention that the classes could either be classes or subclasses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually just do `link_to 'Edit', [:edit, @object]`, assuming `@object` is listed as a resource in your routes file.

Comment: Had no idea you could do that. This can't manage subclasses though, can it?

Comment: Not sure. Try `app.url_for [:edit, Subclass.first]` in the console and see.

Comment: Works well but takes subclasses to parent class' route.

Answer (score 1):

How about use polymorphic_url in rails? You can search the api for it.

```
redirect_to polymorphic_url(yourclassname.constantize.find(yourid), action: 'edit')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
def edit_asset(class, id)
    redirect_to send("edit_#{class.lowercase}_url", id) 
end
```